# How to store cookies from some sites but clear others when firefox closed?

Tags: firefox, cookies

Using Firefox on Windows 7.

I have my cookie settings set up like this:

[image: Firefox Privacy Options]
[image: Settings for Clearing History]

I want to clear all my cookies when I close the browser except for some domains in a list. Is that possible? I thought it might be in Exceptions, but that only lists which sites are allowed, it doesn't affect how long they are stored for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of hese extensions might be helpful: [CookieCuller](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cookieculler/) and [Selectivecookiedelete](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selectivecookiedelete/)

Answer (score 0):

I do that this way:

In 'Clear history when Firefox close' settings, unselect cookies.

In 'keep until:', select 'when firefox close'

And add the site for which you want to keep cookies in exception with 'Allow'.

No need for plugins, and work well.